# Check if Tensor is Placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Placeholders are recognized as Tensors in TensorFlow.

`isinstance(tf.placeholder("float", []), tf.Tensor)` returns `True`

Is there a way to check if a Tensor is a placeholder specifically? Something like:

```
isinstance(tf.placeholder("float", []), tf.Placeholder)
```

Unfortunately for the API I'm building, `tf.Placeholder` is not an actual instance type in TensorFlow.

Comment: Here's an ugly way I managed to do it:

`import tensorflow as tf 

pl = tf.placeholder("float", [])

sess = tf.Session()
try:
    sess.run(pl)
except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError:
    print(pl.shape)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check it with `op.type`:

```
assert tf.placeholder("float", []).op.type == 'Placeholder'
```

Comment: @SamLerman No problem. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.